# Using sample() and for loops to pseudorandomize data in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a set of 44 *.csv files, each representing data from a different participant. The column names are the same for each file. I want to filter by VarA so that x == T, and then randomize VarB for permutation testing. I then want to concatenate the 44 files.

For example

```
 subj   VarA   VarB   filename
  1       T      a      1_a
  1       T      f      1_b
  2       T      g      2_a
  2       F      a      2_b
```

I've previously done this successfully by concatenating all files first, and then randomizing the data using the code

```
 data <- list.files(path = "./MyData/files/",
                    pattern="*.csv", 
                    full.names = T) %>% 
   map_df(function(x) read_csv(x, col_types = cols(.default = "c")) %>%
            mutate(filename=gsub(".csv","",basename(x)))) 

 new.data <- data %>% filter(VarA == T)

 new.data.scramble <- (sample(new.data$VarB))
```

However, this doesn't randomize within participant. I believe that a for loop is the best way to do this, but I'm not familiar with this method.

Answer (score 1):

What you mean by 'randomize VarB' is unclear. Your code example merely shuffles it. Are you doing permutation testing?

Other than that, to be faithful to your example:

You are already using `dplyr`, so it only requires `group_by`, provided the participant is identified in the dataframe:

```
data %>% filter(VarA == T) %>% group_by(filename) %>% sample_frac(size=1, replace=FALSE)
```

However, for *permutation testing*, this will *not* shuffle the observations and their subjects. For that, we have to *update a column*, but we can still do this:

```
data %>% filter(VarA == T) %>% group_by(filename) %>% mutate(varB=sample(varB))
```

Comment: This works - thank you! I've edited the question so hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: I have updated my answer to account for permutation testing.